# On which platforms has ANTLR 4.7 been tested?

Tags: antlr

I need to know if ANTLR version 4.7 has been tested and verified on Windows 10.  Is there any way to know if it supports Windows 10 without having to build the ANTLR code and run the tests myself?

Comment: Why can't you build ANTLR and run tests? What makes you think that it would be OS sensitive? BTW your question is off-topic, since lacking some [MCVE] ...

Comment: Where I work we are about to make the transition to Windows 10, and the administrator insists on knowing if ANTLR (among other programs that we use) has been verified on Win10.  I realize that it shouldn't be OS sensitive, but I need to convince him of that.  As for building ANTLR, to do so I would have to download additional software (such as the Go language), and there is a significant amount of red tape involved in downloading new software at my place of work.

Comment: Then just download that thing and test it. If your bureaucracy requires testing, you need to comply. And yes, management is often stupid.

Comment: BTW, I also work in a highly bureaucratic (French state owned) organization, so you have my empathy. And I am also sometimes asked to do stupid things.

Comment: You are welcome. I mostly helped with my empathy. You just need to run the tests, or at least write a report that you did run them. BTW, I don't think that running the tests takes a lot of time (and it will make you fluent with that ANTLR tool).

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR is written in Java and should run on any version of Windows, Linux or Mac that has a recent version of Java installed.

Therefore, "proof" can be performed in three steps, not necessary on the same system:

1. Check which versions of Java are compatible with ANTLR 4.7. As per documentation, [Java 1.6 should be compatible](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md).
2. Check that compatible version of Java runs on Windows 10. As per documentation, [Java was certified on Windows 10 starting with Java 8 Update 51](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/win10_faq.xml)
3. Check that the target system has a compatible version on Java installed.

I am assuming that OP does not need to recompile ANTLR tool (parser generator) itself so he/she can use the pre-built JAR. If this is not the case, ANTLR tool can also be rebuild on another system.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Do you think something needs to be added?

Comment: I guess the OP's question is mostly motivated by the internal bureaucracy of his organization. We can't help about that.

Comment: I find that a pretty exact answer for the OP's question. What's missing is something about proving that ANTLR works on Win10 without having to build ANTLR there (i.e. by downloading the jar and running a parser generation).

Comment: Added buerocratic details.